# MAGENTO: Upgrade CONNECT ERROR

Tags: magento, upgrade

I need help. How can I solve this issue, I am trying to upgrade my magento to new version.

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.2.1 conflicts with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.0.1, community/Mage_Compiler 1.9.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few things I would do in case of conflict during upgrade:

> 1. Empty /var folder and make sure it is writable and try upgrading again

If it fails,

> 2. Install a fresh version of Magento (later version) and copy your custom files in this newly created instance